# Allow Search on a List or Document Library's Column Data

Tags: 2010, list, search, document-library, search-scope

I have followed the instructions [found here](http://www.tautic.com/refining-a-moss-search-to-a-column-value) to attempt to crawl a Document Library's columns, so that the documents can be searched by additional properties of the List Item.

After setting up the managed properties, I did a full crawl, but my list columns are still not searchable (tested via searching for "term" and "mapped_property:term").

The "Allow items form this list to appear in search results?" setting is correctly set to "Yes" (as in [this MS Office page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/enable-content-to-be-searchable-HA010379092.aspx#_Toc277075191)). And the list is most definitely crawled as I can search by text in the documents, but not the list column data (this also rules out the crawl account not having access).

The user I am searching as is the farm administrator account, so there is no security trimming going on here.

I've also tried following the videos posted [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621097.aspx).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The test search we were running wasn't working because those specific documents were in draft version and had never been published as a major version. The crawl was only picking up published major versions of documents.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you click on the Crawled Properties that your Managed Property mapped to , can you see any sample data.Click [here](https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7106/7639779116_5a1239dfb2_h.jpg) to see the image.

Comment: There are sample documents listed. The crawl logs show only success. The search results still return nothing.